# Best Practices in writing a .NET-based RESTful API

Tags: .net, rest

Earlier this year, the intrepid folks of StackOverflow took great pains to provide us with an API to the StackExchange universe.  They did this the way they do everything else- taking great care to ensure that the API would be bulletproof and well-designed.

I'm starting a project to write a SaaS-based ERP system and it seems that a public API is a likely future requirement for application integration.  Jeff and company made it clear in discussions on StackApps that writing a good public API is *hard*.

My question is:

**What are the things you have to consider when writing a public RESTful API, particularly on the .NET platform?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first decision you need to make is, do you really want to build a RESTful system, or do you want to create a HTTP api.  Those are two different problems.

I've been building a RESTful ERP system for last four years and it is not the same as just creating an integration API.

If you do want to build a RESTful system, then the design of your media types and link relations will be the most important part of the process.